# WCF single vs multiple operations ?. design ideas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture

We are developing a CRM application. All the business logic and data access go through WCF services. We have 2 options for communication between WCF and client (at the moment: ASP.NET MVC 2)

One option is create method for each operations. Example

```
    GetCustomers()
    GetCustomersWithPaging(int take, int skip)
    GetCustomersWithFilter(string filter)
    GetCustomersWithFilterPaging(string filter, int take, int skip)
    or // new .net 4 feature
    GetCustomers(string filter = null, int take = 0, int skip = 0)
     ... list goes..
```

Another option is create a generic single service operation called

**Response InvokeMessage(Messege request)**. Example

```
wcfservice.InvokeMessage(
   new CustomerRequest { 
       Filter = "google", 
       Paging = new Page { take = 20, skip = 5}
   });

// Service Implementation.
public Response InvokeMessage(Message request) 
{
     return request.InvokeMessage();
}
```

**InvokeMessage** = generic single service call for all operation.

**CustomerRequest** = Inherited class from **Message** abstract class, so I can create multiple classes from Message base class depend on the input requirements. 
Here is the CustomerRequest class.

```
 public class CustomerRequest : Message
 { 
   public string Filter {get;set;}
   public Page Paging {get;set} // Paging class not shown here.
   Public override Response InvokeMessage() 
   {
       // business logic and data access
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**

```
public abstract class Message
{
    public abstract Response InvokeMessage();
}
```

// all service call will be through InvokeMessage method only, but with different message requests.

Basically I could avoid each service call's and proxy close etc..
One immediate implication with this approach is I cannot use this service as REST

What is the recommended approach if the service needs to call lots of methods?

thanks.

Comment: My personal belief is that designing a great WS can often times be difficult. Simply regurgitating the back end data to move it to the client is not enough. It really comes down to defining, not regurgitating. If you are ever possibly thinking of making this WS public, do not go the InvokeMessage route, however if this is simply a form of communication internal to the product, I don't think it matters.

Comment: It is internal, but as you said in future it may need to expose some functionality to public; I think in those cases, it is better to expose limited functionality through WCF data services or similar method. thanks for your comment.

Comment: I agree with Aaron, designing a great WS is a difficult task. With that in mind I would say don't worry about the "in the future part" for now. Get your service working for your internal app now and cross that bridge if and when you get to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the facade pattern you can have both.

First, build your services using the first option. This allows you to have a REST interface. This can be used externally if required.

You can then create a facade that uses Invoke message style, this translates the request based on the parameters and calls one of the individual services created in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

As to the question of multiple specific operations vs one general query - either approach could be valid; defining fine-grained vs coarse-grained operations is to some degree a matter of taste.

When faced with a similar requirement in our RESTful service, I've chosen to create a filter class that reads parameters from the query-string, available thusly:

```
public NameValueCollection ReadQuerystring()
{
    return WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters;
}
```

The larger issue that I see here is that you're subclassing Message for your operation parameters - is there a reason why you're doing that?  The best practice is to create data contracts (objects annotated with [DataContract] attributes) for such a purpose.

Comment: @why subclass; I edited my original post to include Message class with abstract method, So If client need new request example: LatePayingCustomers (these are data contracts actually so client see it), then I need to inherited it from Message in order to pass through "InvokeMessage", which in turn call LatePayingCustomers override, this way I get better error handling in both methods.